# Get .pfx Cert File Expiration with pyOpenSSL

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl

I'm trying to use pyOpenSSL to check the expiration of a .pfx file the client will need to use with my application.  We issue the cert to the client, and it expires every two years.  I know using openssl in the command line works, by converting to a .pem and then running '-noout -enddate' on the resulting .pem file.

There is a good chance the client will not have openssl installed, so I'd like to use the library if possible.  How would I check the .pfx expiration date?  I've gotten the cert loaded, but have no idea how to A) convert to a .pem file (if I need to) and B) check the expiration on that .pem file (or encoded string).

Thanks!

So far:

```
import OpenSSL

from OpenSSL.crypto import *
cert_path = 'C:\\Clients\\Omega\\bos.omegaadv.gtssloader.pfx'
p12 = load_pkcs12(open(cert_path, 'rb').read(), 'globallink')
x = p12.get_certificate()

print(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()))
```

code here

Comment: If the user does not have openssl installed, then how are you expecting pyOpenSSL to work? it's just a wrapper around openssl.

Comment: It is?  Holy crap, I thought it was separate.  Thanks for the note, I'll just use OpenSSL in the command line then.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert to x509 after that you can retrieve the expiration date by accessing the property **not_valid_after**

I use the library cryptography for conversion

try it:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

pkcs12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open('cert.pfx', "rb").read(), '1234')
pem_data = crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pkcs12.get_certificate())
cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pem_data, default_backend())
print(cert.not_valid_after)
```

Output:
2019-08-03 19:35:19

Answer (score 0):

To avoid:

> DeprecationWarning: str for passphrase is no longer accepted, use
> bytes

Change four line for:

```
pkcs12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open('cert.pfx', "rb").read(), '1234'.encode('ascii'))
```