# How can I get the company name and expiration date without the password from a .pfx file with pyOpenSSL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pfx, pyopenssl

Can I get the company name and expiration date without the password?

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

pkcs12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open('cert.pfx', "rb").read(), '1234')
pem_data = crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pkcs12.get_certificate())
cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pem_data, default_backend())
print(cert.not_valid_after)
print(cert.subject.rdns[7].__getattribute__('_attributes')[0].value)
```

Comment: Not sure what format the certificate is, but certificates rarely contain a password, the private key does? Or am I completely wrong and this format some how uses it?

Comment: In the case of an A1 type certificate

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911754/3565792

Comment: @LGregianin No, because I still need the password

Comment: If your PKCS#12 (PFX) file is encrypted with a password, you will need the password to read the contents.